# How to create a stacked bar graph from nested dictionary in python without using Pandas library

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

How can i create stacked bar graph from a nested dictionary (e.g. see below) without using the Pandas Library?

```
dct = {'Chesterville': {'Bachelor': 8, 'Diploma': 5, 'Fail (Promoted)': 5, 'HC': 16},
       'Ebony Park': {'Bachelor': 1, 'Diploma': 3, 'Fail (Promoted)': 0, 'HC': 1},
       'Makhaza': {'Bachelor': 15, 'Diploma': 9, 'Fail (Promoted)': 13, 'HC': 4}}
```

Comment: You could try using code. And then when you run into a problem, you can share with us what you tried, and what you wanted it to do that it didn't do.

Comment: Just curious, why not `pandas`? It allows you to plot in one line.

Comment: I am able to understand how to code without pandas. however I know how to plot using dataFrame in pandas. please help me in plotting the graph.

Comment: you can check this out to start: https://python-graph-gallery.com/12-stacked-barplot-with-matplotlib/